Difference between the name used on different documents
All my academic documents have my first and middle names only (e.g., A B), but in my passport includes a surname including first and middle names plus surname (eg. A B C). Basically, all my academic documents don't have a surname, which differs from my passport. But the first and middle names are the same in both the academic and passport documents. Would this be an issue for applying for further studies abroad?

No, it will not. It is not uncommon for author names to differ from passports.

Thatz mean it wouldn't create an issue?

What do you mean by "academic documents"? Diplomas? Transcripts? Or just authorship of papers and such.

Many variations on this question have been posted previously. Some examples: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56457/shortening-my-name-on-papers https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63023/if-the-name-i-used-on-the-publication-is-different-from-my-legal-name-which-one https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/98379/will-having-a-different-academic-name-than-official-name-hurt

https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8603/if-i-publish-under-a-pseudonym-can-i-still-take-credit-for-my-work Some of these may apply more closely to your situation than others. You can find even more by searching "different name" or something similar.

No, that shouldn't be an issue. It is common for academics to slightly change names (e.g., marriage, divorce, etc.). The industry, and journals are prepared to handle this.

I think the question is about the impact on applications for graduate study, not journal submissions.
